# How can I stop editing cell if it is not done with in set time?

Tags: vba, excel

In my office we tally bags with a  barcode scanner, but some times the user edits the Excel cell, giving the bag number manually, so I want to stop manually writing in excel cell.

**That cell must update only by scanner.**

I've tried the code below, and **it returns the keystroke count but not the time.**

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'If Target.Address = Range("A1:A100") Then
    'Enter Code or Call any Function if any process has to be performed
    'When someone Edits the cell A1
    If Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numRows, numCols)).Offset.Value = "" Then
           Call Demo
    Else: End If
End Sub

Sub Demo()
    'Specify a range (change to suit)
    MsgBox CountKeystrokes(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))
    If Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numRows, numCols)).Offset.Value <> "" Then
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numRows, numCols)).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    Else
    End If
End Sub

Function CountKeystrokes(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iCtr As Long
    For Each rCell In rng
        iCtr = iCtr + Len(rCell.Formula)
    Next
    CountKeystrokes = iCtr
End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean `if it's not done in a set time`?  If you are manually editing an Excel cell, you can cancel the edit by pushing [Escape].

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but I'm not sure... is your goal just to prevent manual entry in one cell?